# Failed the capstone project

Tags: graduate-school

I have been given a second chance for completing my capstone project. I went to the director as well as the professor and discuss what I'm going to include in my report and they agreed the data I'll be including in my report. I worked upon it and given my best in making the report as discussed with the director of my department. Now after I submitted the professor failed me again this time giving the excuse that he was not able to understand the report contents and data even after I discussed and taken the approval for my report. I explained him in the mail that what I actually meant in the report and he replied that you wouldn't need to explain me here and you should have explained it in the project. Now they have dismissed me from the University by doing the unfair behaviour with me. I know since it's my second chance even the Dean won't be able to help me and pass me and let me graduate. I paid a huge amount to the university as my fees and they are returning me this unfair behaviour. What can I do if the professor wouldn't able to understand what I wrote in the report that's not my mistake. Please suggest me what action I can take against the professor and what can be done to get graduated. I'm shattered and broken from inside since I'm an international student in United States and I took a loan from Indian Bank to pay the fees. Please suggest me where can I appeal for this wrongdoing happened. I'm in a huge financial pressure

Comment: It isn't clear, exactly, how this is unfair. The money you paid is irrelevant. Only your performance is.

Comment: The professor failed me even after we discussed how I'll be working on my project. And I made the project according to the discussion only. Now what else I would have done?. What is the reason to fail me?. He replied that he couldn't understand what I wrote. Don't you think that this is unfair?

Comment: *What can I do if the professor wouldn't able to understand what I wrote in the report that's not my mistake.* It's incumbent on the writer to make their report understandable. I doubt it was so complex your professor could not understand it. It seems more likely it was poorly written and presented.

Comment: "*What can I do if the professor wouldn't able to understand what I wrote in the report that's not my mistake.*"  Is there anyone else who can understand what you wrote in the report?

Comment: "*I have been given a second chance for completing my capstone project.*"  Students who were *not* given a second chance would probably say that that is unfair.

Comment: Can you give a suggestion what action can I take against the professor. I can't afford to take the professor's behaviour which is unfair which I think. I'm fully confident what I presented in the report. I'll present the concerned authority what I have done in the report. If still they wouldn't agree, I'm ready to accept the dismissal

Comment: Have you had a third party (friend etc.) read your report before submission? What may be clear to you may not be clear to a third party (which is the position a prof would take as a reader). If you haven't done it before submitting (which is the safe practice to do to avoid an outcome like yours), please do so now and let people give their unbiased opinion about your text. Do not induce them to affirm you; you must be neutral - you nee objective, unbiased opinions before taking formal steps. Good luck.

Comment: Yes I showed it to one of my professor and he said that it's a good report. I previously worked under him and he gave me A-grade in that project. I sincerely gave my best in my master's program and succefully completed all the semesters and secured above 3.5gpa in all of them and in first semester my gpa was 4.00. I can't afford to get dismissal just on a report. What should I do now?

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry about your situation. Unfortunately, there is nothing much to do here. It isn't clear that the professor acted incorrectly here; it sounds more likely that you just did not do a satisfactory job on your capstone project, according to his standards, and they (being your professor and the University) do set the rules here. It is up to them to decide whether your performance was good enough.

> I explained him in the mail that what I actually meant in the report and he replied that you wouldn't need to explain me here and you should have explained it in the project.

He is right: like it or not, you are judged based on the report, not on emails you send afterwards. It is  his job to evaluate you and he did not understand your report, so he can't give you a good grade.

> Please suggest me what action I can take against the professor and what can be done to get graduated.

Don't take any action until you are absolutely sure that your capstone project was satisfactory. If it wasn't, then you can't take any action. You seem to have assumed your report was good enough, but it is not clear.

If the professor really has wronged you here, and failed you for no good reason, then you should reach out to others at the university to discuss your situation. Talk to a different professor about it and get a second opinion on the report. Talk to the dean or to your academic advisor.

Comment: +1 for the friendly tone (which is a rarity on this site).